# XNA projects suddenly don't run and Visual Studio freezes after compile

Tags: visual-studio, xna

When clicking the start debugging button, the project builds, it then says build succeeded, then visual studio just freezes, the built project doesn't run. The project's process and parent process (devenv.exe) don't terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Avast! Antivirus, you must disable or exclude your executable from the Avast! DeepScreen scanner.

Comment: Comodo has also been known to cause problems with Visual Studio. In case anyone is having similar problems.